# CSGO Successful connection between client and server, but client kicked out to main menu

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting, networking

I'm trying to setup a dedicated server for CSGO. I've successfully navigated getting the proper login token and I've got ports 27015 TCP/UDP NAT'd to the local address of the server.

When I try to connect from my client, it loads then just kicks me off to the main menu:

> Connecting to public([PublicIP]:27015) ...
> Server using 'public' lobbies, requiring pw no, lobby id ffffffffffffffff
> ChangeGameUIState: CSGO_GAME_UI_STATE_LOADINGSCREEN -> CSGO_GAME_UI_STATE_INGAME
> **** Unable to localize '#GenericConfirmText_Label' on panel descendant of 'MMStatus'
> ChangeGameUIState: CSGO_GAME_UI_STATE_INGAME -> CSGO_GAME_UI_STATE_MAINMENU

In the server I can see the client trying to connect, it assigns a cookie:

> -> Reservation cookie f850318e9dfae8cb:  reason [R] Connect from <[Client public IP]>:27005
>
> Server waking up from hibernation
>
> ---- Host_Changelevel ----

I can even see a successful exchange of packets in wireshark:
[image: pcap]

This is my config:

> ~/csgo_test/srcds_run -game csgo -console -usercon -condeubg +game_type 1 +game_mode 2 +mapgroup mg_allclassic +map de_dust +sv_setsteamaccount [token]

I'm not sure where to go next, I'm hoping someone can point me to the correct place in the console log or some other log file to get more information on why the client can't connect.